# angular watch inside of a directive with out controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am having trouble binding updating $scope.modalClick to scope.modalClick, I thought using the scope:{ modalClick:"=" } would fix it but it does not.  How do I do two way binding from the child scope (**scope**)to the parent scope (**$scope**).

Here is my markup

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/modal.js"></script>
    <style>

        .btn { width:200px; height:30px; background-color:rgb(30, 50, 100); color:white; line-height:30px; text-align:center; }
        .btn:hover { background-color:#005cab; cursor:pointer; cursor:hand; }
        .modal-window-directive { width:100%; height:300px; background-color:orange; background-color:rgba(20, 20, 20, .5); }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div modal-click="partials/form.html" modal-id="modform" bgcolor="rgb(10, 10, 10, .5)" width="400" height="200"class="btn">click me</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my Javascript

```
if(typeof qs === "undefined"){

    window.qs = function(arg){ return document.querySelector(arg); };

}

var app = angular.module("modal", ["ngAnimate"]);

app.run(function($rootScope){

    console.log($rootScope);

});

angular.element(document).ready(function(){

    angular.bootstrap(document.querySelector("html"), ["modal"]);

});

function AppCtrl ($scope){

    $scope.setSource = function(src){



    }

    $scope.closeModal = function(){



    }

    $scope.openModal = function(){



    }

}

app.directive("modalClick", function($compile, $document){

    return {

        restrict:"A",
        scope:{

            modalClick:"@",
            modalId:"@",
            bgcolor:"@",
            width:"@",
            height:"@"

        },

        controller:"AppCtrl",

        link:function(scope, element, attr, ctrl){

            var modalElement = angular.element("<div class='modal-window-directive' style='position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0; width:100%; height:100%;'></div>");

            var modal = angular.element("<div class='modal-window-frame' ng-include='modalClick'></div>");

            angular.element(document.body).append(modalElement);

            if(scope.bgcolor){

                modalElement.css({backgroundColor:scope.bgcolor});

            } else {

                modalElement.css({backgroundColor:});

            }

            modalElement.append(modal);
            $compile(modal)(scope);


            scope.modalActive = false;

            scope.$watch("modalActive", function(newVal){

                if(newVal){

                    console.log("newVal :" + newVal);

                }


            })

            scope.toggle = function(){

                scope.$apply(function(){

                    scope.modalActive = !scope.modalActive;

                })

            }

            element.bind("click", function(e){

                scope.toggle();

            })


        }

    }

});
```

I know there is a way to do it. Am I missing something in my scope? Do I have to find it to the controller in the html? I am not sure how to work this one out can anyone help or point me in the right direction? Should I be using $compile for the angular element?

Comment: i dont think you need this line, you are already doing this by assigning in isolated scope, scope.modalClick = attr.modalClick;

Comment: @Jesse: Did you take a look at my answer ? Did it work for you ?

Answer (score 1):

In order to bind to the parent scope's property, you need to pass it as the value of an attribute and do a two-way data-binding in your isolate scope. Right now you are not passing the property as attribute value.

Furthermore, you don't need a controller in the directive to bind to the parent scope.

Finally, yes, you need to `$compile` the element in order to make it "Angular-aware" (e.g. have that `ngInclude` take effect).

HTML:

```
<div modal-click template-url="modalClick" class="btn">click me</div>
```

Controller:

```
function AppCtrl ($scope){
    ...
    $scope.modalClick = 'partial/form.html';
    ...
```

Directive:

```
app.directive("modalClick", function($compile, $document){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope:{
            templateUrl: '='
        },
        link:function(scope, element, attr){
            /* Now `scope.templateUrl` is 2-way bound 
             * to parent scope's `modalClick` property */

            var modalElement = angular.element('<div class="modal-window-directive"><div class="modal-container-element" ng-include="templateUrl"></div></div>');

            $document.find('body').append(modalElement);
            $compile(modalElement)(scope);
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: I tried it and the $document.append part is not working I used the compile function and its working but I am not understanding the modalClick: '=someNameThatCouldBeAlsoModalClick' part. I am going to post an edit to the code.

Comment: Of course you can't append anything to the document. I updated the code.

Comment: The `modalClick: '=someNameThatCouldBeAlsoModalClick'` part is what takes the variable referenced by the `some-name-that-could-be-also-modal-click` attribute and places it into the directive's isolate scope. So, when you link the compiled element with the directive's scope (by means of `$compile(modalElement)(scope)` the `ngInclude` works, including the template defined in the parent scope's `modalClick` property.

Comment: @Jesse: That long-and-practically-useless-name-kind-of-sucked, so I changed it to "teplateUrl".

Comment: I really appreciate your help I will try the updated code, is there a way to have template-url="modalClick", set the $scope.modalClick in the controller, is that what the  templateUrl: will do? I am still learning the scope part of angular and I hope I am not asking the wrong questions some of this is still a little unfamiliar to me.

Comment: You can't set the controller's property fromthe attribute. But if you do not care to have the value in the controller (i.e. you don't care about `$scope.modalClick`, you can set the tempate url right from the view (but in that case you need to enclose it into `'`: `template-url="'partial/form.html'"` (There are also other ways to set it using one-way data-binding etc, but it is outside the scope of this answer). You should definitely read the documentation about `$compile` - it is very enlightening regarding the inner workings of directives.

Comment: Thanks again you have been a big help. I am still learning $compile.

Comment: @Jesse: If this answer helped you with your problem, please accept (and/or upvote) it.